# PIL: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use PIL to show an image loaded from a list of numbers.

My entire code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

L = 4 #resolution increase

LR_DIM = (2592, 1944)
HR_DIM = (LR_DIM[0]*L, LR_DIM[1]*L)

HR = [0] * (HR_DIM[0] * HR_DIM[1]) 

#include low-res files
LR = []
LR.append([[250 for x in range(LR_DIM[0])] for y in range(LR_DIM[1])])

img = Image.new("L", LR_DIM)
img = img.putdata(LR[0])
img.show()
```

and I got to the last line and get the error in the title.

What's wrong?

I'm on Windows, and using Python32 and a fresh install of both Python and PIL.

Comment: Could you post full traceback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`img.putdata()` returns `None`; it alters the image in place.

Just use:

```
img = Image.new("L", LR_DIM)
img.putdata(LR[0])
img.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty dumb of me!